# Test and Set vs Peterson's Algorithm

Tags: operating-system, locking, mutex

What is the difference between the test and set implementation of `mutex` and the `Peterson's Algorithm?`

Which of them is actually used in the real systems?

Comment: As for the "which of them is actually used" part of your question it would be nice [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you'd find out from some systems with open source code like: `FreeRTOS`, `Linux`, `ReactOS` and link the source code...

Answer (score 2):

Peterson's algorithm doesn't work very well in a modern memory architecture with caching. You end up needing to flush constantly. Test-and-set and interlocked operations like interlocked exchange or interlocked increment are going to be much more commonly used and have direct support on the CPU.

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of "needing to flush constantly"

Comment: I mean flushing the L1 cache so that the other CPUs can see the values of the flags. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache